# sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3@v3.8.7 (in sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3@v3.8.7):

Tags: go, kubernetes, command-line, open-source, development-environment

I was setting up kubearmor developement environment, I used make deploy command and it started downloading sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3@v3.8.7
and the following error was shown in command line. What should i do?
`go: sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3@v3.8.7 (in sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/kustomize/v3@v3.8.7): The go.mod file for the module providing named packages contains one or more exclude directives. It must not contain directives that would cause it to be interpreted differently than if it were the main module. make: *** [Makefile:142: kustomize] Error 1`

i didn't try anything yet

Comment: Please read the description of [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) appropriate to this web site. *"I didn't try anything yet"* ... We can't help then. Your question **may** be more appropriate on  https://superuser.com OR https://serverfault.com .  Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.